# Eclipse associating *.mod files with DTD, validation fails for Jetty mod file

Tags: eclipse, jetty, dtd, eclipse-2020-03

I recently brought an existing maven project into Eclipse 2020-03.  The project contains a jetty folder which itself contains a file:

> modules/somefile.mod

The *.mod file pattern seems to be associated with the DTD content type, and this association is "locked".  Because my file is not a DTD, it fails the validation.
Eclipse's Bugzilla lists a 7-year old bug, Bug 420688, which describes this problem, but the workarounds there don't seem to work for me.
The validation error I get is

> The markup declarations contained or pointed to by the document type declaration must be well-formed.

Is there a way to

1. Disable the validation of this particular file, or preferably
2. Disassociate it from the DTD content type?

Thanks for any advice or direction.

Comment: Look in the Preferences in 'General > Content Types' and 'General > Editors > File Associations' to see what is set for the file type.

Comment: @greg-449, Under Editors > File Associations, *.mod is not explicitly mapped.   In General > Content Types > Text > DTD, there is a "locked" File Association to *.mod (as well as *.dtd and *.ent).

Comment: If it is locked you can't change the association

Comment: Thanks.  Given that, does anyone know if there is a way to disable Validation for the Content Type, or validation on a per-file-basis?  Since *.mod is pretty common in Jetty (I thought), it seems likely people worked around this somehow.

Comment: We just reassigned `*.mod` to the text file association using the preferences UI in the editor.

Comment: Thanks, @JoakimErdfelt, I have added "*.mod" to "General > Content Types > Text, which did change the File type to "Text" instead of "DTD".  I have also explicitly mapped *.mod in "General > Editors > File Associations".  That just seemed to list the editors.  Now even though the "File type" seems OK, it maintains that same validation error.

Comment: Validation warnings/errors/info are cached, make sure you clear all validations (don't remember how to do that) and restart your IDE.